# JavaScript: Google maps mapOptions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm trying to figure out how to convert KM into Miles in Google map in my code.

basically I am displaying a distance and time between 2 locations using Google Maps and everything works fine but the issue that I have is that it displays the distance in KM and not in miles.

is there any extra mapOptions that I could use to get the distance in miles instead?

this is my entire code:

http://jsfiddle.net/1on2yumf/1/

the issue is that it shows the distance in miles in jsfiddle but it shows the distance in kilometers *IN MY PAGE*  which is the strangest things I have ever experienced!

my code is identical to the one shown above in jsfiddle.

Entire Code:

```
<script>
    (function () {


        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService(),
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(),
            createMap = function (start) {
                var travel = {
                        origin : (start.coords)? new google.maps.LatLng(start.lat, start.lng) : start.address,
                        destination : "<?php echo $CUpostCode; ?>",
                        travelMode : google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                        // Exchanging DRIVING to WALKING above can prove quite amusing :-)
                    },


                    mapOptions = {
                        zoom: 2,
                        // Default view: downtown Stockholm
                        center : new google.maps.LatLng(59.3325215, 18.0643818),
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                          };

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
                directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
                directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("map-directions"));
                directionsService.route(travel, function(result, status) {
                    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
                    }
                });
            };

            // Check for geolocation support    
            if (navigator.geolocation) {



                window.onload = (function (position) {
                        // Success!
                        createMap({
                            coords : true,
                            //lat : position.coords.latitude,
                            //lng : position.coords.longitude


                            lat : <?php echo $curLat; ?>,
                            lng : <?php echo $curLon; ?>
                        });
                    }, 
                    function () {
                        // Gelocation fallback: Defaults to Stockholm, Sweden
                        createMap({
                            coords : true,
                            //lat : position.coords.latitude,
                            //lng : position.coords.longitude


                            lat : <?php echo $curLat; ?>,
                            lng : <?php echo $curLon; ?>
                        });
                    }
                );
            }
            else {
                // No geolocation fallback: Defaults to Lisbon, Portugal
                createMap({
                            coords : true,
                            //lat : position.coords.latitude,
                            //lng : position.coords.longitude


                            lat : <?php echo $curLat; ?>,
                            lng : <?php echo $curLon; ?>
                });




            }
    })();
</script>
```

**and this in the header:**

```
<script src="http://maps.google.se/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

any advise would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest defining the metrics explicitly

Just add a ONE line `unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC` in this code as follow:

```
var travel = {
               origin : (start.coords)? new google.maps.LatLng(start.lat, start.lng) : start.address,
               destination : "<?php echo $CUpostCode; ?>",
               travelMode : google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
               unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
               // Exchanging DRIVING to WALKING above can prove quite amusing :-)
},
```